# Got blank value in update query

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Here I am updating query in for loop by passing an array.
Due to array_shift, the id can run on `3 and 4` but the second id is not visible as I pass `3 and 7`

My array:

```
$altxt = array( "", "test", "","", "", "test1", "", "", "", "");
$chk = array( "3", "7" );

for($i=0; $i < sizeof($altxt); $i++)
{
    if(!empty($altxt[$i]))
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=$altxt[$i] where id=".  array_shift( $chk );
    }
}
```

And output giving:

```
update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=test where id=3
update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=test1 where id=
```

As I want in output:

```
update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=test where id=3
update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=test1 where id=7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this by using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-filter.php) and a `foreach` loop:

```
$altxt = array_values(array_filter(array(
  "", "test", "","", "", "test1", "", "", "", ""
)));
$chk = array("3", "7");

foreach ($altxt as $key => $value) {
   echo "<br />update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number='$value' where id=" . $chk[$key];
}
```

**UPDATE**: use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reindex the filtered array in order to match the keys for both arrays.

Comment: Thanks Matei:
I got but here also got one problem is that, when I take array like,
$chk = array("3", "7"); and $altxt woould be the same,
So here, what happens is, the value of $altxt will swap in $chk's id that mean,
3=>test1 and 7=>test.
That is wrong value.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand the problem.. why would it swap?

Comment: The thing is,
As first I select checkbox id=7 and textbox value='First' then
checkbox id=3 and textbox value='Second'

then it will give the result as, 

update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number='Second' where id=7
,
update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number='First' where id=3

This is because I am inserting the checkbox id in session..

Comment: ok.. this is another issue.. you should ask a new question including the html part because this is not related to PHP only, but passing the data through forms also

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($altxt); $i++)
{
    if(!empty($altxt[$i]))
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=$altxt[$i] where id=".  array_shift( $chk );
        unset($chk[$i]);
    }
}
```